# Behavior of the Fourier coefficients at $\infty$ for a particular function $f$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis

- I know that Fourier coefficients $c_{k}$ tend to zero for $k \to \infty$, given some necessary conditions on the function.
- I am trying to prove that given
  $\mathrm{f}(x) \equiv
  \left\vert 1 - \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}x}\right\vert^{-2d}
  \,\mathrm{h}(x)$, with $x \in [-\pi, \pi]$,
  $d \in (-1/2,1/2) \setminus \{0\}$ and $\mathrm{h}$ even, positive and continuous on $[-\pi,\pi]$, and differentiable on
  $[-\pi,\pi] \setminus \{0\}$.
- There are other hypothesis but I don't think they are necessary for this
  ( I mean, there is other stuff going on later which requires further hypothesis, but I am not interested in that ).
- I am trying to prove that, for $k \to \infty$, $c_k \approx k^{2d - 1}$. I tried integration by parts, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: What is $t_k$ in your last point?

Comment: In your second bullet you will probably need that $h$ is also smooth at $0$.

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez I meant $c_k$, sorry. I don't know why my post has been edited like this,also...

Comment: Ok, I think I did it. It was in fact just some quite long and tedious calculations, using integration by parts basically. Not really interesting. I was wondering if the result could come from a more general fact and can be deduced without (or with little) calculations given the particular $f$ we're dealing with